# Improving code string processing

Tags: c#, string

I have this string:
var string1 = numericUpDown2.Text; // 1

always want to contain 4 numbers like 0001 or for "11" = 0011.

I used this code to make it:

```
private string Corection4(string variable)
    {
        var stringlen = variable.Length;
        if (stringlen < 2)
        {
            string corectvariable = "000" + variable;
            return corectvariable;
        }
        if (stringlen < 3)
        {
            string corectvariable = "00" + variable;
            return corectvariable;
        }
        if (stringlen < 4)
        {
            string corectvariable = "0" + variable;
            return corectvariable;
        }
        else
        {
            string corectvariable = variable;
            return corectvariable;
        }
    }
```

Now i need some help to improve this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it easy by `ToString()` method. For example:

```
var correctVariable = variable.ToString("D4");
```

It would add extra zeros to your string.

If you are working on strings, parse it first to int value:

```
var correctVariable = string.Format("{0:D4}", int.Parse(variable));
```

Comment: Thanks for tips, but now i get an error for "D4" argument type 'string' is not assignable to a parameter type System.IFormatProvider

Comment: You should first parse it to int value. Watch at my second example

Comment: for a hex value didn't work 

var value = Convert.ToInt16(numericUpDown3.Text);
var hexOutput = string.Format("{0:X}", value);
var reg = string.Format("{0:D4}", int.Parse(hexOutput));

//output is : 3E4
an i want 03E4

i try 
var reg = string.Format("{0:D4}", hexOutput);
but didn't work

Comment: Ok i solve the problem 
var hexOutput = string.Format("{0:X4}", value);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Format()`

```
int number = 11;
//D4 = pad with 0000
string outputValue = String.Format("{0:D4}", number);
```